# grunt less multiple css files keeping folder structure

Tags: css, gruntjs, less

I have a branding application where I would like to have this output:

- /branding/

  - /default/

    - default.css
  - /brand1/

    - brand1.css
  - /brand2/

    - brand2.css

This one should be output from a branding folder with same structure but with .less files

So I would like to do something like this:

```
less: {
      production: {
        options: {
        },
        files: {
          'dist/branding/**/*.css': 'branding/**/*.less'
        }
      }
    }
```

I just seen examples on this where they all go to same folder, but I want to keep this dynamic because in my case there is like a ton of brandings, and the branding folders have more than just a css file, they also have other artifacts like images and so on.
Any suggestions?

Comment: See http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you want LESS files under `branding` compiled to a `dist/branding` folder and to keep the folder structure.

To do that you would do something like this:

```
files: [
  {
    expand: true, // Recursive
    cwd: "branding", // The startup directory
    src: ["**/*.less"], // Source files
    dest: "dist/branding", // Destination
    ext: ".css" // File extension 
  }
]
```

Comment: Thansk Colin, this did it. Just one note  I have a branding folder with less files and I want it to go css:ed to dist/branding.

Comment: Thanks @EduardoinNorway I have changed my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You can visit http://rajdeepdeb.me/less-to-css-grunt-for-multiple-files/

Add the following configuration in your grunt file

    `...rest of the grunt configuration,
    files: [{
        expand: true,
        cwd: '/',
        src: ['**/*.less'],
        dest: '/',
        ext: '.css',
        extDot: 'last'
    }],
    ... rest of the grunt configuration`